# Difficulty setting view in onDoNext and doOnCompleted methods

Tags: android, observable, rx-android, rx-java2

I am learning RxAndroid and started with a very simple example in my project. i.e. fetching user profile image URL response as observable.

Below is the code to get the string URL value, I use Picasso to load the image URL. The code works fine when I use runonUiThread to load the image, but it throws an error when I use it without it; it says the method call should be in the main thread.

Do doOnNext and doOnCompleted always run on a background thread?

```
picUrlSubscription = getUrlAsObservable()
                         .map(responseBodyResponse -> {
                             Log.d(TAG, "map ");
                             try {
                                 if (responseBodyResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                                     observableStr = responseBodyResponse.body().string();
                                     return observableStr;
                                 } else {
                                     observableStr = "Bad_url";
                                     return observableStr;
                                 }

                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                             return null;
                         })
                         .doOnNext(s -> {
                             Log.d(TAG, "next ");
                             try {
                                 if (s != null && !s.equalsIgnoreCase("Bad_url")) {
                                     observableStr = new JSONObject(s).getString("url");

                                 } else
                                     runOnUiThread(() -> profileCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.profil));

                             } catch (JSONException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                                 runOnUiThread(() -> profileCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.profil));
                             }
                         })
                         .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                             Log.d(TAG, "completed ");
                             runOnUiThread(() -> Picasso.with(this).load(observableStr).into(profileCircle));
                         })
                         .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                             Log.d(TAG, "error "+ throwable.getMessage());
                             observableStr = "bad_url";
                             runOnUiThread(() -> profileCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.profil));
                             return observableStr;
                         })
                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                         .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `doOnNext()` and `doOnCompleted()` run on whichever thread was specified to notify its observers with. If no thread was specified, they will run on the same thread the observable is operating on.

Since you specified `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, the observable will operate on the `io` thread. According to the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html); the `subscribeOn()` operator designates which thread the observable will operate on, no matter where in the chain it appears, unlike the `observeOn()` operator:

> `ObserveOn`, on the other hand, affects the thread that the `Observable`
>   will use below where that operator appears.

Therefore, put your `observeOn()` call *before* your `doOnNext()` and `doOnCompleted()` calls.

Comment: Yes. And then you can get rid of the `runOnUiThread()` calls, and just manipulate the views directly.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is answered, I see a number of issues with this code as far as RX practices go.

1. The main issue is the error handling - you should, if at all possible avoid handling exceptions inside the operators, and rather do it in the subscriber. In the code below, I have removed a lot of repetition from your code by always setting the profile default image in the `onError` part of the subscriber.
2. I would also encourage you to avoid using `doOnNext` / `doOnCompleted` / `doOnError` - those operators are good if you want to add some side-effects to your RX chain (for example, make a call to your analytics tracking) - but rather use the subscriber - what's what it's for. It's especially important to have error handling in the subscriber - it will prevent your application from crashing if something you didn't think of went wrong.
3. Thread jumping in operators. If you wish to perform an operation on a different thread, use `subscribeOn`/`observeOn`

Here is the code with my suggestions:

```
    picUrlSubscription = getUrlAsObservable()
            .map(responseBodyResponse -> {
                String jsonString = null;
                if (responseBodyResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        jsonString = responseBodyResponse.body().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Failed decoding response!");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Bad request URL!");
                }
                return jsonString;
            })
            .map(jsonString -> {
                String profileUrl = null;

                if (jsonString != null) {
                    profileUrl = new JSONObject(jsonString).getString("url");
                }

                if (profileUrl == null || profileUrl.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Profile URL missing in response!");
                }

                return profileUrl;

            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(profileUrl -> Picasso.with(this).load(profileUrl).into(profileCircle),
                       throwable -> {
                           Log.e("TAG", "Failed loading profile image!", throwable);
                           profileCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.profil);
                       });
```

Comment: Yes makes sense.. So as per the code u mentioned in all the throw new exception cases it goes to subscribe's throwable part and sets default image ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Once any operator throws, the rest of the chain will be skipped (with the exception of the operators designed for error handling, such as `retryWhen`) For more complex chains, you might want to handle different exception types differently in your subscriber. It's pretty powerful - you don't worry about catching, and handle all the errors in one place.